AwsParameterStoreEnvironmentRepositoryFactory bean is not available after updating to Spring boot 3.3.1
Recently I have updated the Spring boot 3.3.1 from Spring boot 2.7.18. Using my application I am trying to fetch some data storeed in AWS but just after updating I am getting below exception.

'org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
qualifying bean of type
'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AwsParameterStoreEnvironmentRepositoryFactory'
available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
candidate. Dependency annotations: {}'
Description: Parameter 0 of method
awsParameterStoreEnvironmentRepository in
org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.AwsParameterStoreRepositoryConfiguration
required a bean of type
'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AwsParameterStoreEnvironmentRepositoryFactory'
that could not be found. Action: Consider defining a bean of type
'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AwsParameterStoreEnvironmentRepositoryFactory'
in your configuration.
I tried below things till now:

tried to create manual bean AwsParameterStoreEnvironmentRepositoryFactory
tried compatible versions of 'spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-config dependency
My Pom files is below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-config-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

My application.yml file is below
server:
  port : 9002
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-config-test
  profiles:
    active: awsparamstore
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        awsparamstore:
          region: us-west-2
          prefix: /config
          profile-separator: _
          recursive: true
          decrypt-values: true
          max-results: 5

cloud:
  aws:
    stack:
      auto: false
    region:
      static: us-west-2


eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:9072/eureka
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true

mca:
  config:
    issuer: MCA
    subject: MCA
    privateKey: /etc/configPrivateKey

My main spring boot application is below:
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ConfigMainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigMainClass.class, args);
    }
}

whenever I use @EnableConfigServer, get the exception. Not able to identify the issue. Its just small application with main class. I am using Java17 with Spring Boot 3.3.1 and all the latest relevant dependencies.
